# How to upload multiple image using laravel api?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I am still learning to create API for upload multiple images using Laravel 5.7. when i am trying upload one image via postman, the image can store in database, but  when i am trying upload two or more images, it can not store in database. i don't get an error for this in postman but previewed in postman redirect to my login page .

This is my controller:

```
         $this->validate($request, [
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
        ]);

        if($request->hasfile('filename'))
         {
            $images=array();
            foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
            {
                $photo_name = time().'_'.$request->input('fa_transaction_id').'.png';
                $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/workphotos');
                $image->move($destinationPath, $photo_name);
                $img_url = asset('/uploads/workphotos/'.$photo_name);

                $data = new FA_Transaction_photo();
                $data->fa_transaction_id = $request->input('fa_transaction_id');
                $data->user_id = $request->input('userid');
                $data->photo_name = $photo_name;
                $data->photo_url = $img_url;
                $data->save();
                array_push($images,$img_url);
            }
```

Anyone can help me? or anyone can teach me how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you dump the `$request->file('filename')` to make sure it has multiple files.

Comment: i have dump the  $request->file('filename'), but it automatic redirect to login page

Comment: Hello @RahmatEffendi, can you show me screen shot of postman, You have to send filename[] as key instead of filename for multiple image.

Comment: Also you return response inside for loop, it will return after uploading first image, so put return response()->json() outside of for loop.

Comment: @RaviGaudani i updated my question to put screen shot of postman and i have put response()->json() outside of for loop, but i get same, it redirect to my login page

Comment: Try by adding **Accept**   **application/json** in postman header. I think its API Auth issue.

Comment: @RaviGaudani how to adding Accept application/json in postman?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188038/discussion-between-ravi-gaudani-and-rahmat-effendi).

Comment: How to upload multiple files using Lumen Multiple file upload. [Please try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003164/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-lumen-multiple-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

you have done minor mistake , check your code again you have

> return response()->json in for loop

so only first image is uploaded and stored and then request is returning response

change your code as below :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
   ['userid'=>'required',
    'fa_transaction_id'=>'required',
    'filename' => 'array',
    'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
   ]);

   if($validator->fails())
   {
    return response()->json(['message'=>$validator->errors()->all(),'success'=>0]);
   }

    $trans = FA_transaction::where('fa_transaction_id', $request->fa_transaction_id)->first();

if($trans){
     $this->validate($request, [
    'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
     {
        $images=array();
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {
            $photo_name = time().'_'.$request->input('fa_transaction_id').'.png';
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/workphotos');
            $image->storeAs($destinationPath,$filename);
            $img_url = asset('/uploads/workphotos/'.$photo_name);

            $data = new FA_Transaction_photo();
            $data->fa_transaction_id = $request->input('fa_transaction_id');
            $data->user_id = $request->input('userid');
            $data->photo_name = $photo_name;
            $data->photo_url = $img_url;
            $data->save();
            array_push($images,$img_url);
        }

        return response()->json(['message'=>'Upload Successfully ','success'=>1,'images'=>$images]);

     }else{
      return response()->json(['message'=>'No Files ','success'=>0]);

   }
 }
```

add this header in post man

> Content-Type : multipart/form-data

Comment: Hello @SaurabhMistry, i have tried it, but it not work, it still redirect to login page

Comment: show your route code , and also add controller's full function in your question

Comment: i have updated my question using your post code  @SaurabhMistry

Comment: i got this error in postman

              {
                    "message": [
                    "The filename.0 failed to upload."
                 ],
                    "success": 0
               }

Comment: @RahmatEffendi , i think is it validation error  , please  try updated validation

Comment: yes, i have updated validation but it same error : { "message": [ "The filename.0 failed to upload." ], "success": 0 }

Comment: @RahmatEffendi , first check file uploads without applying validation , if all files are being uploaded , then after validation .